# How are Python Class attributes different from PHP static class properties?

Tags: php, python, static, attributes

Python class attributes and PHP static class properties at the surface appear to function identically (excluding the ability in PHP to add visibility public/protected/private).

Use of either statics or attributes:

- Are tied to the class not the instance
- Must be evaluated at run time
- if you rely on either inside a class method definition you're going to have difficulty achieving complete coverage for testing of that method.

My question is are there any significant differences I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking up python instances for an attribute with the same name as the class variable, it will provide the class variable instead.

In PHP...

```
class C 
{
    static $foo = 42;
}

$i = new C();
var_dump($i->foo);  // null, plus a notice
```

In Python...

```
class C:
    foo = 42

i = C()
print(i.foo)  # 42
```

Even more interesting...

```
class C:
    foo = []

a = C()
b = C()
c = C()

a.foo = ['hello']
b.foo.append('world')

print(C.foo) # ['world']

print(a.foo) # ['hello']
print(b.foo) # ['world']
print(c.foo) # ['world']
```

In other words, be very careful with class variables in Python.

Comment: I think your first example will not say null, but something like `object(C)#1 (0) { } `

Comment: I see, if you in your final example did `print(C.foo)` you'd get the original.  The instances, once they start overriding the original class attribute basically hides it, but don't change the same named attribute for the entire class, just their instance.

Comment: Corrected, you are right, some typing mistakes in there. Added the C.foo example as well.

Comment: I see your edit.  PHP you cannot access statics  the same way as properties of the instance, you'd need to use `var_dump($i::$foo)` so there's no way to mistake them.  Also, you can't have an instance variable the same name as a static, where Python has the danger you mentioned before of same semantics to access class attributes at the class level and instance level